# Problem with updating a text from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I have a button in one component that I want to clear the text from a div's content from another component.

The red button is in the Header component, and the "THE TEXT" is in the CommandLine component. I want when the red button is pressed to clear the "THE TEXT"
I also need that "THE TEXT" input to be less than 10 characters when the user types.

[image]

Here is my Code:

```
CommandLine.jsx
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState, useContext } from "react";
import Result from "./Result";
import { headerCircleIcons } from "../constants";
import { InputContext } from "../contexts/InputContext";

const CommandLine = () => {
    const inputRef = useRef(null);
    const { input, setInput } = useContext(InputContext);
    const [inputError, setInputError] = useState("");
    const [command, setCommand] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        // sets the cursor to the input when page loads
        inputRef.current.focus();
    }, []);

    // sets the cursor to the input when clicked somewhere else
    const handleBlur = () => {
        inputRef.current.focus();
    };

    // handles the downloading of the resume when command : resume is entered
    const downloadFile = () => {
        // Create a new anchor element
        const a = document.createElement("a");

        // Set the href and download attributes for the anchor element
        a.href = headerCircleIcons[1].actionURL;
        a.download = "Ashot Gharibyan Resume.pdf";

        // Append anchor to the DOM (not visible to the user)
        document.body.appendChild(a);

        // Programmatically trigger a click event on the anchor element
        a.click();

        // Remove the anchor element from the DOM
        document.body.removeChild(a);
    };

    const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
        if (e.key === "Enter") {
            e.preventDefault(); // Prevents a new line from being added
            // ----------------- CLEAR -----------------
            setInput(e.target.innerText);
            if (e.target.innerText === "clear") {
                setInput("");
                setCommand("");
                e.target.innerText = "";
            } else if (e.target.innerText === "resume") {
                // ----------------- RESUME -----------------
                setCommand("Thank you for downloading my resume! ");
                downloadFile();
                e.target.innerText = "";
            }

            setCommand(e.target.innerText);
            // setting the div's text to empty string
            e.target.innerText = "";
            setInput("");

            // Clear the input error
            setInputError("");
            console.log("Enter pressed, current input:", input);
        }
    };

    const handleInput = (e) => {
        const maxLength = 10;
        const target = e.target;
        const currentLength = target.innerText.length;

        if (currentLength > maxLength) {
            const selection = window.getSelection();
            const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);

            // Truncate the text
            target.innerText = target.innerText.substring(0, maxLength);

            // Clear previous ranges
            selection.removeAllRanges();

            // Restore the range, setting cursor at the end
            range.setStart(target.childNodes[0], maxLength);
            range.setEnd(target.childNodes[0], maxLength);
            selection.addRange(range);

            setInputError("Max length is 10 characters");
        } else {
            setInputError("");
        }
        setInput(e.target.innerText);
    };

    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col items-start justify-start ">
            <div className="textQuery flex items-center gap-4">
                <span className="flex-none">
                    (ashot_gharibyan_env) hello@Macbook-Pro ~ %
                </span>
                <div
                    ref={inputRef}
                    contentEditable={true}
                    className="textQuery min-w-0 flex-grow whitespace-pre-wrap  break-words rounded border-none p-2 text-[#ffffff] outline-none"
                    onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                    onInput={handleInput}
                ></div>
            </div>
            <div className="text-red-500">{inputError}</div>
            <Result command={command} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default CommandLine;
```

```
Header.jsx
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import CircleButton from "../components/CircleButton";
import { headerMaterials, headerCircleIcons } from "../constants";

const Header = () => {
    const [currentWindowWidth, setcurrentWindowWidth] = useState(
        window.innerWidth,
    );
    const [currentWindowHeight, setcurrentWindowHeight] = useState(
        window.innerHeight,
    );

    const handleWindowSizeChange = () => {
        setcurrentWindowHeight(window.innerHeight);
        setcurrentWindowWidth(window.innerWidth);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("resize", handleWindowSizeChange);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("resize", handleWindowSizeChange);
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <header>
            <div className="flex items-center">
                <div className="flex items-center justify-center gap-x-3 lg:gap-x-2 sm:gap-x-1">
                    {headerCircleIcons.map((icon, idx) => (
                        <CircleButton
                            key={idx}
                            color={icon.color}
                            imgURL={icon.image}
                            altText={icon.name}
                            actionURL={icon.actionURL}
                            iconType={icon.iconType}
                        ></CircleButton>
                    ))}
                </div>
                <div className="flex flex-1 items-center justify-center gap-3">
                    <img
                        src={headerMaterials[0].home_folder_icon}
                        alt={headerMaterials[0].name}
                        className="h-12 lg:h-8 sm:h-5"
                    />
                    <h1 className="textQuery">
                        ashotgharibyan -- -zsh -- {currentWindowWidth}x
                        {currentWindowHeight}
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    );
};

export default Header;
```

```
CircleButton.jsx
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { InputContext } from "../contexts/InputContext";

const CircleButton = ({ color, imgURL, altText, actionURL, iconType }) => {
    const { setInput } = useContext(InputContext);

    return (
        <div
            className={`group box-border flex h-16 w-16 items-center justify-center rounded-full lg:h-8 lg:w-8 sm:h-6 sm:w-6 ${color}`}
        >
            <a
                href={actionURL}
                className="invisible group-hover:visible"
                {...(iconType == "resume"
                    ? { download: "Ashot Gharibyan Resume" }
                    : {})}
                {...(iconType == "clear"
                    ? { onClick: () => setInput("") }
                    : {})}
            >
                <img
                    className=" h-10 w-10 object-scale-down lg:h-6 lg:w-6 sm:h-4 sm:w-4"
                    src={imgURL}
                    alt={altText}
                />
            </a>
        </div>
    );
};

export default CircleButton;
```

```
App.jsx
import { InputProvider } from "./contexts/InputContext.jsx";
import {
    Header,
    Footer,
    CommandLine,
    Demo,
    Result,
} from "./sections/sections.js";

const App = () => {
    return (
        <InputProvider>
            <main>
                <section className="bg-[#3F3836] px-8 py-4 text-3xl text-[#BAB3B2]">
                    <Header />
                </section>
                <section className="h-screen bg-[#1e1e1e] px-8 pt-4 text-3xl text-white">
                    <section className="">
                        <Demo />
                    </section>
                    <section className="">
                        <CommandLine />
                    </section>
                </section>
                <section className="px-8">
                    <Footer />
                </section>
            </main>
        </InputProvider>
    );
};

export default App;
```

I have tried few ways, but when I get the button to clear it out, the validation for the maximum of 10 characters doesnt work. it just lets you write it. I have tried having a Context and putting the input variable into the context, that clears the text but makes the validation not work.

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";

export const InputContext = createContext();

export const InputProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [input, setInput] = useState("context");
    return (
        <InputContext.Provider value={{ input, setInput }}>
            {children}
        </InputContext.Provider>
    );
};
```